# Why does the node module for @material have multiple default exports?

Tags: .net, typescript, npm-install

So here's a carbon copy of my index.d.ts file (node_modules/@material/auto-init/index.d.ts)

```
    /**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
 * THE SOFTWARE.
 */
import { MDCComponent } from '@material/base/component';
import { MDCFoundation } from '@material/base/foundation';
export interface MDCAttachable {
    new <F extends MDCFoundation>(root: Element, foundation?: F, ...args: Array<unknown>): MDCComponent<F>;
    attachTo<F extends MDCFoundation>(root: Element): MDCComponent<F>;
}
/**
 * Auto-initializes all MDC components on a page.
 */
declare function mdcAutoInit(root?: Document): MDCComponent<MDCFoundation<{}>>[];
declare namespace mdcAutoInit {
    var register: (componentName: string, Constructor: MDCAttachable, warn?: (message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]) => void) => void;
    var deregister: (componentName: string) => void;
    var deregisterAll: () => void;
}
export default mdcAutoInit;
export default mdcAutoInit;
```

So obviously this is an internal startup file for the @material module, notice at the bottom it has two identical lines for the default export...

First of all, I'm not even sure if there should be two exports (I let npm install create all of my node modules, so I'd give it the benefit of the doubt)

But as far as Typescript is concerned, this is a build error, and you cannot have multiple default exports.

I'm new to TypeScript and this codebase in general, the version of TS I'm using is 4.2.4